# "Eventually" vs. "finally"

Tags: meaning, differences, adverbs

What is the difference between *finally* and *eventually*?

> - He eventually escaped and made his way back to England.
> - He finally escaped and made his way back to England.

Answer (score 36):

The two words are very similar, and can indeed be used interchangably in many contexts – but not always.

A good way to figure out the subtle nuances of each word is by consulting a thesaurus.  For example, if you want to imply something will happen after a long wait, you would not use *finally*:

> The Eagles will win a championship eventually.

But you could use *finally* after the fact:

> The Eagles have finally won a championship!

If you want to say that something is the last of a sequence of steps, you would not use *eventually*.  For example, on a cooking show:

> Finally, put the lasagne into the oven, preheated to 350 degrees.

But you might use *eventually* to say that you'll get around to doing something later:

> That was a great lasagne; time for a nap!  We'll do the dishes eventually.

You knew I'd get to the thesaurus entries eventually, right?

> ## eventually
>
> adverb
>
> *the culprit will be caught eventually:* IN THE END, in due course, by and by, in time, after some time, after a bit, finally, at last, over the long haul; ultimately, in the long run, at the end of the day, one day, some day, sometime, at some point, sooner or later.

Finally, here's the entry for *finally*:

> ## finally
>
> adverb
>
> 1. *she finally got her man to the altar:* EVENTUALLY, ultimately, in the end, after a long time, at (long) last; in the long run, in the fullness of time.
> 2. *finally, wrap the ribbon around the edge:* LASTLY, last, in conclusion, to conclude, to end.
> 3. *this should finally dispel that common misconception:* CONCLUSIVELY, irrevocably, decisively, definitively, for ever, for good, once and for all.

Comment: What a nice way to explain your point! And the result is also entertaining. +1.

Answer (score 9):

**He eventually escaped and made his way back to England.**
*This connotes a gradual progress in his mission to escape, he must have faced several troubles before he was able to escape. Possibly he was caught or lost several times before he reached England.*

**He finally escaped and made his way back to England.**
*This carries a sound of expectation, as if the escape was long-awaited. He must have planned his escape long ago and was able to escape when he put his plan into action.*

Both the adverbs mean 'in the end' or 'at last' but they differ in the emphasis, former is a long and gradual (step by step) process and the latter is long awaited.

Comment: Very nice!  Well done.  One more thought: if an author didn't want to express either one of those sentiments (that is, if the escape was neither long and gradual, nor long-awaited), one could simply write: "He later escaped and made his way back to England."

Comment: Since the escape was neither gradual nor long awaited, i think the author may get rid of "later" in his statement. It totally depends on the story prior to the statement, though. Cheers!!

Answer (score 4):

I could not find any reliable source which points out the difference between "finally" and "eventually". Some may say the difference is in emphasis or the number of series or longer time! But I think the difference between them is that you use finally to introduce the last point you want to make, and you can use eventually to say what the result or outcome of something was. [ldoce](http://www.ldoceonline.com) reports:

- Use **finally** or **eventually** to say that something happens after a long time.

> Finally we managed to get the car to start.
>
> When she eventually turned up, the food was cold.

- Use **eventually** or **in the end** to say what the result or outcome of something was.

> They eventually got bored and went home.
>
> In the end we decided to cancel the trip.

- Use **lastly** or **finally** to introduce the last point you want to make, the last action in a series of actions, or the last item in a list

> Lastly, I would like to remind you that smoking is not allowed.
>
> Load the paper, select the number of copies, and lastly press 'Print'.
>
> You add flour, salt, and finally milk.

Answer (score 3):

Both "finally" and "eventually" suggest waiting for a period of time. "Finally" suggests something occurring at the end of a sequence of events (relating to the word "final"), and also has connotations of exasperation and overcoming something. "Eventually" also suggests something at the end of a series of events, but without an absolute finality. The two words can generally be used interchangeably, at least in the above example, without much meaning being lost.

In short, "finally" = "eventually" in the above example.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think "finally" implies we are not interested in what was after. If "something finally happened" it is that "something" we were interested in. "Eventually" on the other hand is rather used as a condition. As in "eventually something happened" would mean that "something" allows "something else" to happen/continue.

Comment: It will be nice if you explain how is 'finally' same as 'eventually' in the example. I will still give it to you if 'finally' = 'at last' = 'ultimately' (and maybe 'in the end' too), but i don't think finally = eventually is correct.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: What about if we changed the equation to "finally ≈ eventually"? (i.e., 'is roughly equal to').  I agree with your answer below, and Sebastien's answer above. In one sense, you eloquently described a very subtle difference that might sway an author to select one word over the other. Yet I can also easily imagine contexts where either word could be used, particularly at the end of a relatively short synopsis. Some dictionaries list "finally" as a definition of "[eventually](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Eventually)", so it's hard to argue that they can never be equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

They have more or less the same meaning and impression. However:

- *Finally* has a meaning of some kind of difficulty or effort
- On the other hand, *eventually* has a meaning like "that's taken a little longer than expected"